# Enforced TLS being delivered as secure email

Tags: email, cpanel, tls1.2

My Web-server sends emails to one of our clients who uses Mimecast.com enforced TLS. We Send our emails to our client via gmail.com using secure TLS via our web server. Our SSL certificate is up to date and so is the client we are sending emails to. Delivery is successful but when the client sends us any emails Mimecast turns that message into secure message. Basically you have to log into their secure email web-app and access the emails from there.
This is not convenient for us.

[image: TLS checker]

It appears that my TLS is working correctly, but every time they send me an email it uses their secure mail web-app (as if my TLS is not working). MimeCast declined to help. How do I ensure that my email-servers TLS will work with mimecast's email server?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Yes I had to allow use of older protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the sort of SSL/TSL that was allowed on my web server was not compatible because it was too new. I updated the webserver to allow older protocols.